# Android Studio call trace gets cleared after app crash

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, android-logcat, android-debug

I'm trying to follow some **call trace** due to some native library crash when I resume or pause the app (random crash). I want to find out the calls that happen before the crash.

I started the debugger, I put breakpoints in onResume and onPause, the debugger stops at the respective breakpoints and under **Debugger->Threads** dialog I can see the call stack, but when the app crashes the debugger prints the call stack for a few milliseconds and then clears the stack logs leaving the window with the message **"Frames are not available"**.

How can I see the stack trace even when the app crashes? Or how can I see the full(history) call trace(like in eclipse)? Thx

Comment: Better option is to integrate your app with crash reporter like [Acra](https://github.com/ACRA/acra) or [Crashlytics](https://try.crashlytics.com/) or [any of these](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/21) so that you can get crash report once app crashes.

Comment: Native crashes kill the app, unless you have a native debugger (like gdb) attached. If you can identify the native call that causes the crash you can put a Java-language breakpoint right before the call, but once the app dies there's not much the JDWP debugger can do.